# Python whoosh - get all unique values from an index field

Tags: python-3.x, whoosh

I have an index of git repositories and I'm saving the name of the repository the file belongs to in each document. The repository field format is `{section}/{repo}` and it is a TEXT field.
I want to achieve pretty simple thing: list of all repositories in the index, i.e. **list of all unique values in the `repo` field**.

When i'm using the

```
result = searcher.search(query.Every(), groupedby="repo")
for item in result.groups():
    print(item)
```

the value are printed with the field values split on the "/", so i'm effectively loosing the `{section}` portion of the repo value.

I have added `sortable=True` to the repo field and reindexed the whole thing. Now it is returning the correct format of the repo value, but only one when i expect it to be about 10. I see that the `_facetmaps` field in the "result" object has incorrect values - missing all the repos except one.

Answer (score 1):

The current solution seems to be to make repo an ID field an use `searcher.lexicon("repo")` to get the list of unique values

https://bitbucket.org/mchaput/whoosh/issue/407/searched-with-groupedby-returns-incorrect